# Why UIImage is Blurry after Cropping in Slider?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, cgimage, cgimageref

I am using this code for my slider for cropping image for UISlider when i am Dragging Slider then image is Blurring how can it without Blurring and Losing without its Clarity

```
- (UIImage *) revealedTrackImageForCurrentValues {
    //Get left and right x positions
    float lowerHandleWidth = _lowerHandleHidden ? 2.0f : _lowerHandle.frame.size.width;
    float upperHandleWidth = _upperHandleHidden ? 2.0f : _upperHandle.frame.size.width;
    float xLowerValue = ((self.bounds.size.width - lowerHandleWidth) * (_lowerValue - _minimumValue) / (_maximumValue - _minimumValue))+(lowerHandleWidth/2.0f);
    float xUpperValue = ((self.bounds.size.width - upperHandleWidth) * (_upperValue - _minimumValue) / (_maximumValue - _minimumValue))+(upperHandleWidth/2.0f);

    //Crop the image
    CGRect croppedImageRect = CGRectMake(xLowerValue, 0.0f, xUpperValue - xLowerValue, self.trackImage.size.height);
    CGImageRef croppedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self.trackImage CGImage], croppedImageRect);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedImageRef];
    CGImageRelease(croppedImageRef);

    return croppedImage;
```

}

how can i do it without lossing image clearity ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edited Code:

You have to subclass UIImage:

#### UIImageView+Cropping.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (Cropping)
- (UIImage *)revealedTrackImageForRect:(CGRect)croppedImageRect;
@end
```

#### UIImageView+Cropping.m

```
#import "UIImage+Cropping.h"

@implementation UIImage (Cropping)


- (UIImage *)revealedTrackImageForRect:(CGRect)croppedImageRect
{
    //create drawing context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(croppedImageRect.size, NO, 0.0f);

    //draw
    [self drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-croppedImageRect.origin.x, -croppedImageRect.origin.y)];

    //capture resultant image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //return image
    return image;
}

@end
```

And then call your code:

```
#import "UIImage+Cropping.h"

- (UIImage *)revealedTrackImageForCurrentValues 
{
    //Get left and right x positions
    float lowerHandleWidth = _lowerHandleHidden ? 2.0f : _lowerHandle.frame.size.width;
    float upperHandleWidth = _upperHandleHidden ? 2.0f : _upperHandle.frame.size.width;
    float xLowerValue = ((self.bounds.size.width - lowerHandleWidth) * (_lowerValue - _minimumValue) / (_maximumValue - _minimumValue))+(lowerHandleWidth/2.0f);
    float xUpperValue = ((self.bounds.size.width - upperHandleWidth) * (_upperValue - _minimumValue) / (_maximumValue - _minimumValue))+(upperHandleWidth/2.0f);

    // Get rect
    CGRect croppedImageRect = CGRectMake(xLowerValue, 0.0f, xUpperValue - xLowerValue, self.trackImage.size.height);

    //Get cropped image
    UIImage *croppedImage = [self.trackImage revealedTrackImageForRect: croppedImageRect];

    return croppedImage;
}
```

Comment: it gives me error in this line    [self drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-croppedImageRect.origin.x, -croppedImageRect.origin.y)]; what i do ??

Comment: @MayankPatel Please check updated code. It's written on the fly but should work

Comment: UIImage *croppedImage = [self.trackImage revealedTrackImageForRect: croppedImageRect]; ,,,it gives me in this line error no interfact UI declares

Comment: Did you import UIImage+Cropping.h into your class?

Comment: Yes i imported in class

Comment: I just tested it, it's working perfectly fine for me. I don't know where you made the error. Hard to tell from here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61034/discussion-between-mayank-patel-and-freshking).